# run a function on all the spark executors to get licence key

Tags: apache-spark

before beginning to scan a database, all the executors need a licence file. I have a function licenceFileInstaller.install() that downloads the file at the right location on the system, which works fine on the master node. How do I run this on all the executors ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you use this method in rdd transformations, it should serialize this method and send it across all the nodes. Like you can use this method within mapPartitions and it will be distributed across all the nodes and run once for every partition.
`rdd.mapPartitions( x => ( licenceFileInstaller.install() ...further database code ))`

Also, I guess you can add that license file using `sc.addFile()` which will be distributed across all the nodes.

You can refer to Spark closures for further understanding